# Changing the injected dependency in all depending instances

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Suppose I have an IoC container that injects a dependency `Dependency` into some classes.

```
public class A
{
    A(Dependency d) { _d = d }
}

public class B
{
    B(Dependency d) { _d = d }
}
```

It if `B` should be able to change the dependency, such that `A` can access the new dependency, then how could that be done in a good way?

Comment: Expose the dependency as a property.

Comment: Why would you want `B` to change the dependency? The whole point of Dependency Injection is that consuming classes have *no* control over their dependencies. Could you share more information about the motivation for asking this question?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Suppose `B` is loading information from a file that's needed elsewhere in the program. `B` knows how to load stuff.

Comment: Then `B` should be a Service that other code can query to get the loaded information.

Comment: @MarkSeemann So `B` should be injected instead?

Comment: If `A` requires `B`, then inject `B` into `A`.

Answer (score 0):

If possible make the dependency a singleton, so that you have side effect
so that when you change the dependency in class B, a see the change, 
because the object tha you pass at the class A and B are the same.